# Conditionally put border-radius on Bar in recharts

Tags: reactjs, recharts

I have an issue with the BarChart Stacked component from Recharts. I don't want to have this whitespace between these two bars.

[image]

I tried to add a conditional rendering with the Cell component, but there is no radius property.

```
<Bar dataKey="savedGain" stackId="a" fill="url(#colorUv_blue)" 
     name="Secured gain with AB Tasty" stroke={false} 
     barSize={20} radius={[25, 25, 0, 0]} strokeWidth={4} />

<Bar dataKey="gain" stackId="a" fill="url(#colorUv_turquoise)" 
     name="Uplift with AB Tasty" stroke={false} 
     barSize={20} strokeWidth={4} radius={[25, 25, 0, 0]} barCategoryGap={0} />
```

Feel free to edit.

EDIT:
I tried the following [tuto](https://github.com/recharts/recharts/issues/280), but i can't modify the border radius..

Comment: did my answer help?

Comment: No unfortunately :(

Comment: if add sample code in [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/) is better for debugging.thanks

Answer (score 1):

if you pass a prop in then you could conditionally render like this:

`radius={props.shouldHaveBorderRadius ? [25, 25, 0, 0] : [0, 0, 0, 0]}`

this is saying if `props.shouldHaveBorderRadius` is true then use `[25, 25, 0, 0]`, if it's false then use `[0, 0, 0, 0]`

obviously you need to define the logic behind this: `props.shouldHaveBorderRadius`

Comment: I want to access to the data for the bar, and i don't have the data by the props ..

Comment: @jibeeeee yes but where are you getting that data from?

Comment: I didn't iterate on the props for display the bar, i cannot access on the radius on a single bar .. :(

Comment: yeh but what I'm saying is, you need to do some logic to work out if there is 1 bar or 2. if there is 1, it's fine. if there is 2, then you pass in a prop to `<Bar />` called `hasTwoBars` or something else. then you can use `hasTwoBars` to identify what border-radius to show

Comment: I'll try this, i'll tell you :)

Answer (score 1):

Good news! You finally can do it in 2022. This code worked for me, but i got typescript issue so need to use ts-ignore because it typed as `number | string | undefined`.

```js
<Bar
   stackId="a"
   dataKey={item.key}
   fill={colors[index]}
   >
    {data.map((entry, i) => {
      const isRadius = index || !entry[requestResults[1].key];
       return (
       // @ts-ignore
       <Cell key={`cell-${index}`} radius={isRadius ? [8, 8, 0, 0] : undefined} />
         );
       })}
  </Bar>
```

Comment: Thanks for ur answer, i will update my code to see if it work with your code :D